# Error in UIApplicationMain when targeting iOS 6 in Xcode project template

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to developing in Xcode so I'm sorry if this is a simple fix.

The steps to reproduce the problem are

- Create a new project in Xcode based on the MasterDetail template
- Running this project is OK
- In the deployment target change "7.0" to "6.0" in the
  popup menu
- Running this project throws an error:

  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
  reason: '-[XYZMasterViewController setPreferredContentSize:]: unrecognized
  selector sent to instance 0x1d08fd10'

I suspect that the problem is due to some syntax or configuration change related to or in `main.m` between iOS 6 and 7 maybe -

```
@autoreleasepool {
     return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([XYZAppDelegate class]));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, `setPreferredContentSize` [is only available in IOS 7.0](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/preferredContentSize). You can search in your code for `preferredContentSize`, remembering that maybe `setPreferredContentSize` are being called using dot notation.

When you found the `setPreferredContentSize` you should do:

```
    if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredContentSize:)])
     {
         // iOS 7
         controller.preferredContentSize = ...;
     }
     else
     {
         // iOS < 7
         controller.contentSizeForViewInPopover = ...;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme. I commented out `self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);` in `awakeFromNib` but the project still did not run on an iPad running iOS 6

Comment: How do you know that is an iOS 7 only method? I can't find it in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203

Comment: Peter,you can check at https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/preferredContentSize. When you comment out the line, you still got the same error?

Comment: Yes I still get the same error. Are there any changes that I should make to the storyboard?

Comment: Are you sure there's no any other place using preferredContentSize? You can added an exception breakpoint (click at the + button on the bottom of debugger tab). He will stop in the line where the exception occur, or in the assembly code if is an external lib

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in autoreleasepool it throws this error when i step into it - `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<XYZMasterViewController 0x2086c530> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Menu.'`

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the Core Data Framework or its a Universal app?